# Não consigo preencher e nem posicionar o background color

Tags: html, css

Estou precisando de uma ajuda. Criei um  dentro de uma div da seguinte forma. Com essas codificações não consigo preencher corretamente o background e nem posicionar ele. Gostaria que ele ficasse, na parte de baixo do Banner

```css
.company-info-background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #DDD;
    opacity: .9;
}
```

```html
<div class="company-info-container">
    <div class="company-info-background"></div>
    <div class="company-info-titlebox">
        <h2>Seja bem-vindo ao noso site</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vel mollis erat, nec semper magna. Donec vitae sapien in ligula venenatis tincidunt.</p>.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas respostas!

Answer (score -2):

O problema aqui é que seu `.company-info-background` está definido como `height: 100%`, porém essa configuração apenas funciona quando o elemento pai tem um valor de altura fixo pré-definido. No caso o seu elemento pai `.company-info-container` não tem um valor de altura pré-definido, por tanto assume que sua altura é automaticamente a soma da altura máxima de todos os elementos filhos (`.company-info-background` e `.company-info-titlebox`) e como `.company-info-background` está definido como `height: 100%` em uma situação que não é possivel, ele assume que sua altura máxima é a do seu conteudo; e como essa div está vazia, sua altura é 0.

no caso, definir uma altura para `.company-info-container` resolve o problema:

```css
.company-info-container {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.company-info-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #DDD;
  opacity: .9;
}
```

```html
<div class="company-info-container">
  <div class="company-info-background"></div>
  <div class="company-info-titlebox">
    <h2>Seja bem-vindo ao noso site</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vel mollis erat, nec semper magna. Donec vitae sapien in ligula venenatis tincidunt.</p>.
  </div>
</div>
```

Porém agora há outro problema. Adicionei uma borda vermelha em torno do container `.company-info-container` para mostrar os limites do elemento pai, mas se notar a div `.company-info-titlebox` está saindo para fora do elemento pai, e isso pode ser um problema; há varias formas de se resolver isso, mas acredito que posicionar o `.company-info-titlebox` de forma absoluta ao `.company-info-container` seja o mais simples:

```css
.company-info-container {
position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.company-info-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #DDD;
  opacity: .9;
}

.company-info-titlebox{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="company-info-container">
  <div class="company-info-background"></div>
  <div class="company-info-titlebox">
    <h2>Seja bem-vindo ao noso site</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vel mollis erat, nec semper magna. Donec vitae sapien in ligula venenatis tincidunt.</p>.
  </div>
</div>
```

Mas se a função do `.company-info-background` for apenas adicionar um background, e posicionar o `.company-info-titlebox` no fim do banner, você pode obter o mesmo resultado assim:

```css
.company-info-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #DDD;
  opacity: .9;
}
```

```html
<div class="company-info-container">
  <div class="company-info-titlebox">
    <h2>Seja bem-vindo ao noso site</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vel mollis erat, nec semper magna. Donec vitae sapien in ligula venenatis tincidunt.</p>.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Lyan!